# UPDATE и переменная с кодом html - как?

Tags: mysql, php, переменные, html, update

Здравствуйте, хешкодовцы))
Помогите, пожалуйста:
Есть переменная, содержащая код описания продукта в виде html кода. Именно в таком вде необходимо поместить это описание в базу. Пытаюсь UPDATE'ом через переменную:

```
$description=$_POST['description'];
mysql_query("UPDATE `data_true` SET `description`=$description WHERE `id`=$i");
```

Самое интересное, что когда передаю 1, к примеру, то ячейка обновляется и становится 1, но когда передаю код html, то просто ничего не меняется.

Как можно решить этот вопрос?

Если нужно: ввожу через textarea, как видно POST-запросом при нажатии submit'a. Тип поля в мускуле - text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, вопрос решен так:

```
$description=iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']));
mysql_query("UPDATE `data_true` SET `description`='$description' WHERE `id`=$i");
```

То есть проблема была в кодировках... Ну и все же спасибо terantul'у за ответ про экранизацию. Потому и не получалось, что кодировка другая была... (то есть оно экранировало, но не могло засунуть в мускул)

Answer (score 0):

[mysql update экранирование кавычек html](https://www.google.com.ua/search?num=100&newwindow=1&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&q=mysql+update+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA+html&oq=mysql+update+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+rfdsxtr+html&gs_l=serp.1.0.30i10.58948.60729.0.61891.8.8.0.0.0.0.114.812.3j5.8.0....0...1c.1.58.serp..3.5.516.N1lW7rvGxfg)

Comment: Спасибо за "содержательный" ответ. Про экранизацию я знаю. Пробовал mysql_real_escape_string(); - не помогло. Да и экранирует оно только \r\n
Еще предложения есть?..